# Watts per wheel on my cyclocross

Tags: tire

I have a pair of `Continental Cyclocross Race, 700x35c, folding` for my Fuji Cross 2.0 cyclocross. I just bought a pair of `Continental Grand Prix 24`. I had a look at [this study](http://www.biketechreview.com/tires_old/images/AFM_tire_testing_rev9.pdf) where different tires where tested and their wattage per wheel has been listed.

Can anyone tell me how much difference in this "wattage per wheel" measure I have with my new and previous tires?

Comment: I don't anybody would be able to tell you that without conducting a lab test. What is "wattage per wheel" anyway? What actual significance does it have?

Comment: It's not clear (at least, not to me) from that pdf that you linked what "watts per wheel" represents. Wheels don't produce watts, *you* do. Perhaps it's supposed to be the amount of watts it takes to overcome the rolling resistance of the wheel? That's just a shot in the dark though. It could also represent the watts that the rider generated per wheel. A little background info about this study might help, like the goals and findings of the researchers.

Comment: I am a beginner cyclist and actually thought that this phrase was well known. I'm sorry for the confusion. I understood it like the less wattage, the less power the rider need to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are an elite-level professional cyclocross athlete, you will never have to worry about the rolling resistance of your cyclocross tires. And at that point you will be able to pay someone else to worry about those things for you.

Comment: I often use my CX for road racing, so that is why I am curious

Comment: I do the same thing, but you said you were using cyclocross tires. If you're trying to compare cyclocross tires to road tires, that's like trying to compare a motorcycle to a truck, they're designed to do completely different things. Even still, if you're a beginner, don't worry about what effect your tires have on your power. Concentrate on your technique.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the top of the report you will see "Power per Wheel at 25 mph with 100 lb load". The Watts per wheel is how much power they needed to apply to get the 25mph.

The reality for cross is that you should be selecting them for very different reasons (how they grip, roll, etc).

Comment: I should never have mention I ride a CX.I often use it for road trips, so I'm still curious about the different performance of the tires